# Deep linking doesn’t work in secured NiFi

Tags: security, kerberos, apache-nifi, spring-security-kerberos

Sub: Deep linking doesn’t work in secured NiFi

I have configured NiFi with Kerberos authentication. When I open deep link to access a processor group, it redirects to login page for authentication but after successful login, it navigates to root URL instead of that particular processor group.

Jira link found for this support - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3035

I didn’t configure **SPNEGO**. Even LDAP authentication won’t work for deep link access. It navigates to login page and enter root URL after successful login. 
Deep link works fine when no authentication enabled. But it fails when it navigates to login page for authentication and then enter to root URL instead of actual URL (Processor link).

Is this support added only for normal mode? How can I achieve this in Kerberos mode?

Thanks,
Matheswaran.S

Answer (score 2):

Once the user has logged in I believe the deep linking should work. I don't believe that when the user needs to log in with their credentials, either using the native NiFi login page or through an SSO provider, the deep linking PG coordinates are not currently retained.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4474